# What exception type does close() throw?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I use serial port access with the standard open(), read(), **close()** functions from unistd.h (Linux).

The whole thing is wrapped with a SerialAccessor class, whose destructor wants to call close(). However, close() is not marked as __THROW, so lint complains that an exception is not caught which is a bad thing in a destructor.

The problem is: what is the correct type to catch since it is not one of the known std-classes?

This does not help, here lint states that "..." is not catched:

```
#include <unistd.h>

try
{
    close (fileHandle);
}
catch(...)
{ }
```

Anyway, I would prefer to catch a proper class / type instead of using "...".

unistd says:

```
/* Close the file descriptor FD.

This function is a cancellation point and therefore not marked with
__THROW.  */
extern int close (int __fd);
```

Comment: In this particular case lint complains unreasonably. There's nothing you need to do to make your program more correct, so the solution to your problem shifts to making lint shut up. Not sure what the best way to do that would be.

Comment: Lint is right: the catch is useless because close will never throw anything. So instead of modifying the Lint settings, the source code should be changed

Answer (score 3):

close() does not throw C++ exceptions: it returns 0 on success and -1 if an error occurs.

If -1 is returned, then you have to check errno to understand what went wrong (http://linux.die.net/man/2/close)

Answer (score 3):

As `close()` is marked as a cancellation point, when you are running a multithreaded programs, and you call `close()`, another thread can gain control and cancel your thread.

This means that your thread can no longer continue to run, but the runtime system may need to do some sort of cleanup. On *some* O/S's, this is achieved by the system call throwing an exception which you should not catch (which also means you should be very very careful about writing `catch (...)` because it can catch some strange things).

See also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433989/posix-cancellation-points)

Ah: Found the one I wanted: The runtime throws the `abi::__forced_unwind` exception and you *must* rethrow it, a little like this:

```
try
{
    close (fileHandle);
}
catch (abi::__forced_unwind const &)
{
     throw;
}
catch(...)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **EBADF** - The argument supplied was not a valid file descriptor
2. **EINTR** - The function call was interrupted by a signal
3. **EIO** - An I/O error occurred

Comment: None of those are exceptions; they are error codes.

Comment: Indeed, I've mixed the notions!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the lint warning for that line; `close` does not throw.

Comment: Lint is correct: ... will never be caught because there is nothing that throws an exception in there